# Android InAppBrowser events not firing in phonegap-build

Tags: sencha-touch, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Im loading an external page with InAppBrowser and it seems like neither loadstart nor loadstop are been fired on Android. My code:

```
var ref = window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=yes;');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() {
    console.log('loadstart!');
    console.log(event.url);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of checks should fix it for you.

1. Make sure you load the right cordova-2.x.x.js file

   ```
   // Platform: android
   ```
2. Include the InAppBrowser plugin in res/xml/config.xml

   ```
   <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
   ```
3. Write the correct white-list tag (differs from iOS)

   ```
   <access origin="https://domain.com" subdomains="true" />
   ```
4. You **really** have to include onDeviceReady like in the example files, that did the trick for me.

   ```
   document.addEventListener('deviceready', app.onDeviceReady, false);
   ```

Comment: thanks for the response, but the issue is on Phonegap-Build :)

Comment: Aha. In that case, only check 4 matters.